# Visual Basic Radio Buttons with Submit Button

Tags: vb.net

I want the user to click on a radio button and then click the submit button. Once the submit button is pressed it changes a textbox value. However Visual Studio is telling me that I need to use a 'Raised Event'. I don't know how to use that or is it even needed? Here is the code:

```
   Private Sub create_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
            Me.creflag.Text += "1"

        ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
            Me.creflag.Text += "4224"

        ElseIf RadioButton3.Checked = True Then
            Me.creflag.Text += "2"

        ElseIf RadioButton4.Checked = True Then
            Me.immune.Text += "619659263"
            Me.typeflag.Text += "4"
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: add this to your sub.. Handles mybutton.Click

Comment: what is the name of your `button` (i guess its `create`)?  is it really a [Button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button(v=vs.110).aspx) object or something else?

Comment: Adding the Handles didn't seem to work. And yes the name of the button is 'create'. I believe its just a standard button object.

Comment: if it is just standard button, change `RoutedEventArgs` to `EventArgs` as you don't/can't use it, I guess..and add the handler  `Handles create.Click`

Comment: Added it but still is giving me errors. Here is the xaml if it is of any use:<Button x:Name="create" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Create" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="396,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>

Comment: Ah its a WPF application? which is beyond my knowledge..hope someone else can help you

Answer (score 1):

In your XAML markup you have

```
.... Click="Button_Click"
```

this means that you need to have a RouterEventHandler named Button_Click not create_Click

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        Me.creflag.Text += "1"

    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
        Me.creflag.Text += "4224"

    ElseIf RadioButton3.Checked = True Then
        Me.creflag.Text += "2"

    ElseIf RadioButton4.Checked = True Then
        Me.immune.Text += "619659263"
        Me.typeflag.Text += "4"
    End If
End Sub
```

[See MSDN docs and examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found out that I was mixing windows forms and WPF together. In windows forms it's .Checked but in WPF that is an event thus why it was giving me errors. The correct way in WPF is .IsChecked

Final Code:

```
Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button.Click
    If RadioButton1.IsChecked = True Then
        Me.creflag.Text += "1"

    ElseIf RadioButton2.IsChecked = True Then
        Me.creflag.Text += "4224"

    ElseIf RadioButton3.IsChecked = True Then
        Me.creflag.Text += "2"

    ElseIf RadioButton4.IsChecked = True Then
        Me.immune.Text += "619659263"
        Me.typeflag.Text += "4"
    End If
End Sub
```